# AR(1) + white noise = ARMA(1,1)

Tags: time-series, autoregressive

Suppose that $x_t$ is an AR(1) process given by $(1-\rho L)x_t=u_t$ where $|\rho|<1$ and $u_t \sim iid(0,\sigma_u^2)$. Consider $y_t = x_t + e_t$ where $e_t \sim iid (0,\sigma_e^2)$.

Then, $y_t$ is an AR(1) model with white noise(WN) measurement error. It seems that there is a well known result that "AR(1) + WN =ARMA(1,1)". I tried to prove this as follows:

$(1-\rho L)y_t=(1-\rho L)x_t + (1-\rho L) e_t$
$\Leftrightarrow$　$(1-\rho L)y_t=u_t + (1-\rho L) e_t$
$\Leftrightarrow$　$y_t= \rho y_{t-1} + u_t + e_t-\rho e_{t-1}$  (*)

If $u_t$ is absent, this is exactly the ARMA(1,1) model. However, due to the presence of $u_t$, this is not exactly the standard ARMA(1,1) process.

I'm wondering if there is a way to represent (*) as the standard ARMA(1,1) process by newly defining a random variable rather than using $u_t$ and $e_t$.

Comment: Hi: since $u_t$ and $v_t$ are iid normal, you can just add them and think of it as a new iid normal  RV and the current noise of the transformed process and you're done.

Comment: Hi: Note that my argument holds because as long as the autcorrelations ( at all lags ) ) of two invertible ARIMA processes are the same, then the processes are the same. There's a proof of this somewhere but I wasn't able to track it down.

Comment: Many thanks. Intuitively I understand your comment. But I want to have an expression of $\varepsilon_t$ in terms of $u_t$ and $e_t$ such that $\varepsilon_t + \theta \varepsilon_{t-1}=u_t + e_t -\rho e_{t-1} $.

Comment: Hi: The first example in this is not the same as yours but you can use the same approach in your case. Basically, you end up with two equations and two unknowns.  I hope it helps. http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~zhu/ams586/SUM.pdf

Comment: Many thanks! The result was a bit complicated than I expected!

Comment: Hi: yeah, in general,  it's not necessary to go through all the algebra. if you have two iid processes, just add them to make that process look the same as the other. ( like I did in my initial comment ).